# Which dice game has a board with 9x9 squares that has different colors on the diagonals and midway on some edges?

Tags: identify-this-game

Can anyone identify this game?

It's played on a board of 9 by 9 squares, some of which (on the diagonals and midway on some edges) are different colours, reminding me of an abbreviated Scrabble board, but rather than tiles, the players cover the squares with cubes that have various coloured symbols on their faces.

The picture seems to show a board slightly more than 1 ft. square, with the squares and cubes having edges of 1-1.5 in.

[image: https://media.npr.org/assets/img/2019/04/04/mentoredit-11_custom-5894e1c412f038c989b0c0f5b6123766735979fa-s1300-c85.jpg]

Comment: They look like Mahjongg cubes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a dice version of the match-3 (3 alike or 3 different) game "Set". It's cleverly enough called "[Set Dice](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/160441/set-dice)"